# Dynamic url change into seo friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns

A very common problem, but couldn't fix the issue.

I want

```
 http://website.de/page.php?module=helios
```

into

```
 http://website.de/page/helios
```

I have tried lots of .htaccess code like this one, but still page sends to 404.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?module=$1
```

Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: sorry, i have edited it.

Comment: page is not directory, its a page.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?module=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: well i couldn't understand, i have tried all answers including yours, but still page is sending to 404 page.

Comment: for more information, i am also using other code in htaccess, like to remove php extension, for sub domain. I don't think those are somehow affecting.

Comment: i got it. i just place your code right at top of other code and works everything. just last info need, i haven't use "Options -MultiViews" from your code, but still working. So is it necessary to use ?

Comment: Not needed for your case so you can leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /page.php?module=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this use your base path

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?module=$1
```